# elementary OS 6 Odin BCM43142A0 (WIFI) NOT WORKING

Tags: wifi, drivers

I was installing ElementoryOs on my HP Laptop. One of the most important things of a laptop is carring it arround and the wifi driver isnt working I have tried a LOT of things linux kernel, bcmwl-kernel-source etc and its still not working.

When I go to Settings then i go to System then to Firmware I see BCM43142A0
When I run lspci -vnn | grep Network
I get 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

When I use iwconfig
I get
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the relevant part of this guide for the relevant version?
https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/

Comment: It doesnt work, I have tried it